# 10BASE-T1L and Ethernet-APL

Tags: ethernet

Concerning a demo project I want to build, what is the difference between 10BASE-T1L and Ethernet-APL?

Are there development kits for Ethernet-APL?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Physical_Layer) tells you that "Ethernet-APL is a specific, single-pair Ethernet based on 10BASE-T1L as defined in IEEE 802.3cg,[1] with additional provisions for process industries". "Are there development kits for Ethernet-APL?" is really a 'shopping' question and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the difference between 10BASE-T1L and Ethernet-APL?

Ethernet-APL is an implementation of 10BASE-T1L. I don't know if there are any development kits out there that use it, but you could reach out to some PHY manufacturers like TI and Analog Devices and ask.